# How to add CORS header to response served from StaticHttpHandler of Grizzly server in Jersey 2?

Tags: java, static, cors, jersey-2.0, httphandler

How to add headers CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods) to every Response file for files served by staticHttpHandler in Jersey (version 2.2)?

I have tried to add CorsResponseFilter but it doesn't help for static content.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8081/";
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("org.example");
    rc.register(CorsResponseFilter.class);
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);

    File dir = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath());
    StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler(dir.getPath());
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/data/");

    System.out.println("Press Enter to stop Restful service");
    System.in.read();
    server.shutdownNow();
}
```

This CorsResponseFilter class adds headers for every Response which comes from Resources classes of Jersey Application. But it not adds headers for static files. I also checked in browser and postman that files are accessible (but without cors header). And I have error message trying to fetch files from javascript single page application.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
    public static HttpServer startServer (String base) {
       final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.mypackage");
       rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
       rc.register(new CORSFilter());
       rc.register(CORSFilter.class);
       rc.register(JacksonFeature.class);
       HttpServer server =  GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(base), rc);
       CLStaticHttpHandler staticHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(MainServer.class.getClassLoader(), "static/" );
       staticHandler.setFileCacheEnabled(false); // change to true in the deploy time
       server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHandler, "/");

      CompressionConfig compressionConfig
            = server.getListener("grizzly").getCompressionConfig();
      compressionConfig.setCompressionMode(CompressionConfig.CompressionMode.ON); // the mode
      compressionConfig.setCompressionMinSize(1); // the min amount of bytes to compress
      compressionConfig.setCompressableMimeTypes("text/plain", "text/html"); // the mime types to compress
      return server;
  }
```

This is the CORSFilter class

```
   import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
   import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
   import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

   public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {

      MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

      headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
      headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    }
   }
```